# Specific RSS & Sharepoint scenario

Tags: sharepoint, rss

I have a special scenario in sharepoint that im trying to get working but im stuck.

What i'm trying to do, is Listen to a RSS feed, and when something new pops send an email to a user that is listed in a sharepoint list column.

Any ideas how to get that working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom SPJobDefinition
2. Set the run frequency to be every 5 mins
3. In the Execute method

   - Download the RSS
   - Check for new items
   - Send email
   - Store the last (rss poll time/last rss item) in a list

Comment: Good idea!
I'll try it and let you know how it went!